# Antiderivative of the product of a quadratic function, an erf function and the gaussian density function

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, error-function

I'm trying to find a closed form formula for the integral below:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} [a(x-b)]^2 \cdot erf(\frac{a(x-b)}{\sqrt{2}}) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} exp(-\frac{1}{2}x^2) dx,
$$
where $x$ is real, and $a, b$ are positive real.

I find Formula 6 in Section 4.3 of this [table](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf) looks related (screenshot below),
[image]
but I'm not sure how to apply a change of variable to get the desired formula, because my integral has a shifted erf. I also found a related post for the product of $x$ with erf and gaussian density [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2662259/integral-of-a-shifted-gaussian-distribution-with-an-error-function), but it integrates over $(0, +\infty)$ and the most recent answer did not show the steps. What are some techniques that I can try? Thank you!

Edit: Some attempt of change of variable and integration by parts.
Let $y=x-b$, then the integral becomes
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}  \exp(-\frac{1}{2} b^2) \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} a^2 y^2 \cdot erf(\frac{ay}{\sqrt{2}}) exp(-\frac{1}{2}y^2) exp(-by) dy.
$$
Let $$
u = y^2 \cdot erf(\frac{ay}{\sqrt{2}}) exp(-\frac{1}{2}y^2), dv = exp(-by) dy,
$$ then
$$
du = [2y \cdot erf(\frac{ay}{\sqrt{2}}) exp(-\frac{1}{2}y^2) + \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} ay^2 exp(-y^2) - y^3 erf(\frac{ay}{\sqrt{2}}) exp(-\frac{1}{2}y^2)] dy, \\
v = -\frac{1}{b} exp(-by). 
$$ There will be another integral without a known formula in $\int v du$, that is,
$$
\int y^3 erf(\frac{ay}{\sqrt{2}}) exp(-\frac{1}{2}y^2) exp(-by) dy.
$$

Comment: Trying $x-b=y$ probably only has the problem of part of the integral as $\exp\left(-\frac {y^2}2-by-\frac{b^2}2\right)= \exp\left(-\frac {y^2}2\right) \exp\left(-by\right) \exp\left(\frac{b^2}2\right) $. Your formula does not account for the $e^{-by}$.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Yes, I tried a change of variable and integration by parts as you said, but it ends up with an integral of the cube of $y$ multiplied with erf and a shifted gaussian density, which I don't know how to solve. I wrote down the steps in the last edit, could you take a look?

Comment: Expand the term in $[ \dots]$ in your first equation. You need the integrals $\int \operatorname{Erf} \times \text{gaussian}$, $\int x \operatorname{Erf}\times \text{gaussian}$, $\int x^2 \operatorname{Erf} \times \text{gaussian}$. Each of these may be found by first [evaluating](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028788/integrating-frac12-sigma-sqrt2-pi-int-infty-infty1erf-fracz-mu-i/4031039#4031039) $Z(J)=\int dx \ \operatorname{Erf}(Ax+B)e^{-Cx^2+Jx}$ and then differentiating the result wrt $J$.